# NoSuchElementException Unable to find element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, java

Can someone help me fixing `NoSuchElementException`. Let me explain what I am trying to do.

I am trying to login into an application with multiple sets of data. Lets say,

1) Valid username and password.

2) Valid username and invalid password.

Now what's happening is, I am trying to find element is present or not.

In my first case, element is present as user successfully loggedIn. But in my second case, user is not logged in and i am trying to find element present inside application after login.

Can any one tell me how to find a solution for such situation ?

```
wd.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(UserName);
wd.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(Password);
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
try
{
  Boolean ispresent =   wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='service_panel']")).isDisplayed();
  if(ispresent)
  {
   //doing something.
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution : Write one method for element present or not and call it.**

### 1]

**Method :**

```
public static boolean checkElementPresent(WebElement webe)
{
    try
    {
        if(webe.isDisplayed())
        {
           //doing something.
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

**Just call below line in your code :**

```
Boolean ispresent = checkElementPresent(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='service_panel']")));
if(ispresent)
{
        //doing something.
}
else
{
        // Do something
}
```

---

### **2]**

**Another Solution is :**

```
try
{
      Boolean ispresent = 
      wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='service_panel']")).isDisplayed();
      if(ispresent)
      {
        //doing something.
       }
       else
       {
        // Do something
       }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   // Do something
}
```

---

> Reason : isDisplayed() method throws exception if element is not present in HTML DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sagar. I tried verifying url and got the solution. Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if(!driver.findElements(By.id("<id-of-the-element>")).size>0){
 //then do your normal operation
}
else{
//do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Mayank. I tried verifying url and got the solution. Appreciate for your help.